# Update powershell keyboard bindings to be emacs style like bash shell

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, terminal, git-shell

I'm fairly familiar with the default bash shell shortcuts (emacs style). For example, if I want to move my cursor forward by a word I would press <kbd>Alt+F</kbd> (same as you would in emacs). I can get to the previous command with <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd>.

Is it even possible in windows powershell to override these shortcuts? If so, does anyone know of a good way to map the default bash shell shortcut configurations to powershell (in a bash shell you can say `set -o emacs`, for example)?

If it helps, I don't really care about powershell per say, I care about posh-git shell. However, git-shell inherits its properties from powershell from what I can tell.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can do that with the `PSReadLine` module which ships with PowerShell 5.0 (Windows 10).

Simply set the `EditMode` option to `Emacs`:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Emacs
```

In addition to the default `Windows` mode, it also has a `Vi` mode.

The [project README file](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) mentions that neither are fully implemented so don't expect full feature parity, but I can confirm that it switches tab completion to bash-style and supports the <kbd>Alt+F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> key bindings for moving forward and jumping to the previous command respectively

*(I'm not an experienced emacs user so I'm unable to tell whether this comes "close enough" to what you expect)*

Comment: That did work for powershell. Thanks! Unfortunately, the posh-git shell still didn't like it when I included this command in the default profile. Have you used the posh-git shell at all?

Comment: @mwm314 No, unfortunately I don't use posh-git (your question said "git-shell", I tested with the Git Shell that comes with GitHub Desktop for Windows)

Comment: Ctrl + A, Ctrl -E, Ctrl -P, Ctrl-N work well at least. Very helpful

Comment: This setting only lives in the current session. how could I make it take effect permanently

Comment: @yuzhen Add it to your [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles)!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks, BTW, you have to generate a Powershell profile script by typing $profile, secondly, grant Set-ExecutionPolicy to unrestricted, finally paste your run time settings into your newly created script and restart PowerShell. not so easy.

Comment: Vim $profile 
Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Emacs
Add the above  line into $profile 
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
Restart powershell ( How to make it permanently emacs style)